# How to get the gaps between sequential numbers from data stored in SQLite using android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sequential

I am developing an android application as my final school project and I came to a problem.

I've created a table in SQLite which stores the information from users like ID, Name, Phone, Email Address etc. but I'd like to insert the data in an ordered way to always insert users using sequential ordering. In my Add_new_user_activity I have an EditText field which I want to be dynamically auto set with the next available ID from the existing ID's in the table, but I don't know how to handle the gaps that could be generated if an user is deleted between two sequential IDS.

Let say that I have this sequential records on the table:

Users from 1 to 50 with it's corresponding ID's.

Then I delete the 27 and 29 user.

The next time I want to add a new user I want the EditText to know that there is a gap between the ID 26 and 28 and take the 27 for the new user ID and do the same if I add new users. In this case if I add 2 more new users their respective ID's would have to be 29 and 51.

Is there a way to solve it efficiently?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to have this behavior? Without a good reason you should not do something that complicated...

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do sounds dangerous, as that's not the intended use of AUTO_INCREMENT.

If you really want to find the lowest unused key value, don't use AUTO_INCREMENT at all, and manage your keys manually. However, this is NOT a recommended practice.

Take a step back and ask "why you need to recycle key values?" Do unsigned INT (or BIGINT) not provide a large enough key space?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more field in your DB say "deleted" and whenever you delete a user just set it to 1. Now whenever you have to add a new user first you need to get list of user-ids having 1 in "deleted" field in ascending order. The first value of the list will hold the desired ID. Then you may just update the value having that ID. If you got no such field, go for insert with incremented ID.